# jQuery new buttons have been created, but will not get erased

Tags: jquery, html, css

The following code is able to add buttons, but the newly created buttons aren't functioning. What is going wrong? How do I select and remove the newly created buttons? I just have performed the jQuery tutorial from W3Schools and found some examples, but they use different code and I want to understand of what I'm doing wrong. I hope you can help.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#min").hide();
  $("#plus").click(function() {
    $("#min").show();
    var row =
      "<div class=\"container\">\n" +
      "<input type=\"text\"/>\n" +
      "<input type=\"button\" id=\"plus2\" value=\"+\"/>\n" +
      "<input type=\"button\" id=\"min2\" value=\"-\"/>\n" +
      "</div>\n";
    $(this).parent().after(row);
  });
  $("#plus2").click(function() {
    $("#min").show();
    var row =
      "<div class=\"container\">\n" +
      "<input type=\"text\"/>\n" +
      "<input type=\"button\" id=\"plus3\" value=\"+\"/>\n" +
      "<input type=\"button\" id=\"min3\" value=\"-\"/>\n" +
      "</div>\n";
    $(this).parent().after(row);
  });
  $("#min").click(function() {
    $(this).parent().remove();
  });
});
```

```css
div.container {
  border: 1px solid red;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="main">
  <fieldset>
    <legend>fieldset</legend>
    <div class="container">
      <input type="text" />
      <input type="button" id="plus" value="+" />
      <input type="button" id="min" value="-" />1
    </div>
  </fieldset>
</div>
```

Comment: One issue is that your code duplicates IDs and they must be unique.

Comment: I totally agree, later on I will enhance my JS skills

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is more than likely because when the function runs, `#plus2` does not exist. You simply need to delegate your click statement(s) like so:

```
$('.main').on('click', '#plus2', function() {
```

However, if you want to make this much better, you should use classes instead of ID's which will greatly reduce the amount of JavaScript code needed. You can also use the clone function so you don't need to write out any HTML strings in your JS

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.min').hide();
  $('.main').on('click', '.plus', function() {
    $('.min').show();
    var row = $('.container').eq(0).clone();
    $(this).parent().after(row);
  });
  $('.main').on('click', '.min', function() {
    $(this).parent().remove();
    if ($('.min').length == 1) {
      $('.min').hide();
    }
  });
});
```

```css
div.container {
  border: 1px solid red;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="main">
  <fieldset>
    <legend>fieldset</legend>
    <div class="container">
      <input type="text" />
      <input type="button" class="plus" value="+" />
      <input type="button" class="min" value="-" />1
    </div>
  </fieldset>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use delegated events instead.

```
$(".container").on("click", ":button", function(){
            $("#min").show();
            var row =
                "<div class=\"container\">\n"+
                    "<input type=\"text\"/>\n"+
                    "<input type=\"button\" id=\"plus3\" value=\"+\"/>\n"+
                    "<input type=\"button\" id=\"min3\" value=\"-\"/>\n"+
                "</div>\n";
            $(this).parent().after(row);
        });
```

In the code above you set event delegation on the parent element, and define to listen to click event that occurs on input elements with type button or button elements, when event occurs it bubbles up to the parent element (in our case .container) .

From [JQuery Site](https://api.jquery.com/on/):

> Delegated events have the advantage that they can process events from
>   descendant elements that are added to the document at a later time. By
>   picking an element that is guaranteed to be present at the time the
>   delegated event handler is attached, you can use delegated events to
>   avoid the need to frequently attach and remove event handlers. This
>   element could be the container element of a view in a
>   Model-View-Controller design, for example, or document if the event
>   handler wants to monitor all bubbling events in the document. The
>   document element is available in the head of the document before
>   loading any other HTML, so it is safe to attach events there without
>   waiting for the document to be ready.
>
> In addition to their ability to handle events on descendant elements
>   not yet created, another advantage of delegated events is their
>   potential for much lower overhead when many elements must be
>   monitored. On a data table with 1,000 rows in its tbody, this example
>   attaches a handler to 1,000 elements:

```
$( "#dataTable tbody tr" ).on( "click", function() {
    console.log( $( this ).text() );
});
```